# React doesn't insert image as background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image

I'm creating a web page and I took a jpg and pgn image to put as a background.

But by no means does it appear on the page.

```
import './Entrada.css'


const Entrada = () => {
return(
    
    <div style={{ 
        backgroundImage: "url(/secoes_02.jpg)"
      }}>
        <div><img src='secoes_02.jpg'/></div>
        <div className='texto'>testatastastasta</div>
    </div>
    
  )
}
export default Entrada
```

In the code above I can place the image as a figure, but I cannot as a background.
I've already tried to insert it by Css and tried import to.

```
 .geral{
background: url("/public/img/partes/secoes_02.jpg");
}
```

But in no way does it appear in my react.
I already reinstalled the nodejs packages and changed the folder location.
And the error continues.
Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting both images in the browser console—both the successful and the failed one? Do they both show up in the stylesheet inspector? See which URLs they are trying to point to; it could be that the relative path is being computed differently for some reason. In that case, you'll see requests for both under the "Network" tab and can figure out which is the right one.

Comment: I tried adding into a div in one of my own projects. It worked no problem. But I used the full url for my image. Not a relative url. 

Does it work for you if using a full url? If so, you need to pay attention to the paths.  If your image is in the public folder, your might want to use the [environment variable to refer to it.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it plz. It works for me.

```
import footer from '../../assets/images/footer.png';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
      <footer style={{ background: `url(${footer})`, backgroundSize: "contain" }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. worked for me

js:

```
   render() {
    return (
    
      <div className="bgimage">
          <div className='texto'>testatastastasta</div>
      </div>
      
    )
}
```

css:

```
.bgimage {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://business.adobe.com/content/dam/dx/us/en/products/magento/open-source/open-source-marquee-2x.png.img.png);
}
```

Height is given 100%, based on your need you can adjust.